# Servicio Forms de Google Apps Script desde Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-apps-script, google-forms

Estoy trabajando en la investigación para el desarrollo  de una app móvil tipo explorador web que abre una página, para poder así trabajar en el modo offline de Google Forms.

Sé que tengo que utilizar esta el [servicio Forms](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/) de Google Apps Script para el desarrollo de dicha aplicación, pero no sé de que manera implementarla en un navegador web e integrarla al proyecto en Android Studio.

¿Podrían ayudarme explicandome cómo o por dónde iniciar?

Comment: * Realice un intent que te dirige hacia el navegador web en este caso el sitio de Google Forms, mi idea es poder una vez cargada la pagina poder trabajar el modo offline.                                                                              
¿Podrían ayudarme explicándome cómo o por dónde iniciar?

Answer (score 1):

A diferencia de los documentos, hojas de cálculo y presentaciones, los formularios de Google (Google Forms) no cuenta como un modo sin conexión (offline).

En relación a la segunda parte, puedes usar "[REST API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/rest/api)" de Google Apps Script (Execution API) para llamar a Google Apps Script y sus distintos servicios. En la página referida se incluyen ejemplos para varios lenguajes, incluyendo Java.